# Thrust vector slice/view

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have a matrix (row oriented) inside a `thrust::device_vector<T>`. Is there any way to get a slice/view of that vector (that would also be of type `thrust::device_vector<T>`)? I'm not interested in copy constructors as those create new vectors and use memory.

So basically assuming we have a vector `thrust::device_vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5,6}` I'd like to do `thrust::device_vector<int> vec_view = vec.slice(2,4)` that would be a view pointing to `{3,4}`.

Need to run certain computations on it in batches and the method I'm using takes only `thrust:device_vector<T>` (no iterators etc.).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this that I am aware of.

Thrust doesn't expose a `device_vector` constructor which accepts an existing `device_pointer`. Were that the case, you could potentially implement you own device_pointer which supported strided access or slicing, etc. But I don't know of a way to achieve what you envisage without recourse to fancy iterators, and apparently those are not viable for your use case.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was afraid of. Guess I'll just have to do without it somehow. Wondering if that's just a `thrust` shortcoming or was it not done due to some other concerns.

Comment: all the thrust containers were modelled after the SGI STL/C++ standard library, and they don't offer anything like this. The obvious model to use would be something like `boost::range`, but that is still an iterator, not a container. It seems to me that the problem is really with the API you are using. If it was written to accept iterators, we wouldn't be having this conversation.....